# What is the fastest card in libCDS, provided that it should be able to expand and erase data?

Tags: c++, lock-free, libcds

I want to use an associative container from libCDS in my project. The problem is that there are a lot of them in libCDS. Please advise which card is better to use, provided that it should be able to expand and erase data.

Comment: Fastest for what operations and what usage-pattern?  Read-mostly?

Comment: @PeterCordes, In general